# Kendo data viz bubble chart - xField and yField data

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

In all the demos for bubble charts I can only see numeric data used for the xField and yField. Is it possible to use string fields? when I try the strings do no appear.

(Using java script version)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

x and y axis should be numeric only. Use parseFloat js function to convert the string to integers before feeding them to the chart.